# Does a compact manifold require non zero Ricci curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Imagine we have a Riemanian compact manifold. Does the compactness necesarily make its curvature non zero? If the answer were no, does anyone know any such manifold with isometry group $U(1)\times{}SU(2)\times{}SU(3)$?

Comment: By  "Euclidean compact manifold", do you mean a compact manifold embedded in a Euclidean space"?

Comment: @RobertLewis no, in physicists' parlance, I mean that all dimensions are space-like

Comment: @silvr: in mathematical parlance that is called Riemannian (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_geometry) as opposed to pseudo-Riemannian or Lorentzian. Euclidean sometimes has a more specific meaning, namely flat Riemannian.

Comment: @silvr: also, can you please edit the second part of your name? Some might find it offensive.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan maybe some might find it offensive but I see no reason why. It insults no one.

Answer (score 4):

No. In fact compact Riemannian manifolds can have zero sectional curvature; take flat tori $\mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$ where $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the usual Euclidean metric and $\Gamma$ is a lattice.

Apparently [every compact Lie group is the isometry group of some compact Riemannian manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87070/can-every-lie-group-be-realized-as-the-full-isometry-group-of-a-riemannian-mani), but I don't know how cavalier one can be about specifying its curvature.

Comment: You Definitely cannot prescribe such isometry group for the flat metric. However, Ricci-flat metric is a different matter.